# C# LevenshteinDistance algorithm for spellchecker

Tags: c#, levenshtein-distance

Hi i'm using the levenshtein algorithm to calculate the difference between two strings, using the below code.  It currently provides the total number of changes which need to be made to get from 'answer' to 'target', but i'd like to split these up into the types of errors being made.  So classifying an error as a deletion, substitution or insertion.

I've tried adding a simple count but i'm new at this and don't really understand how the code works so not sure how to go about it.

```
static class LevenshteinDistance
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the distance between two strings.
        /// </summary>
        public static int Compute(string s, string t)
        {
            int n = s.Length;
            int m = t.Length;
            int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];
            // Step 1
            if (n == 0)
            {
                return m;
            }
            if (m == 0)
            {
                return n;
            }
            // Step 2
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
            {
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
            { 
            }
            // Step 3
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {

                //Step 4
                for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    // Step 5
                    int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;
                    // Step 6
                    d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                        Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                        d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
                }
            }
            // Step 7
            return d[n, m];
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up the algorithm itself, on google, so that you can better identify the steps, what they are, and how they work...then keep 3 integer counters outside the loop (global variables or reference parameters).  Increment the appropriate counter at each step, as necessary.

Comment: Also, from the looks of things, you will need to re-write the algorithm so that when assigning the cost portion of things, you will be able to determine what you are doing.  Generally speaking, the algorithm itself doesn't actually care what the step itself is, only that it needs to be made, so you will need to add the detection portion of it so that you know what its doing.

Comment: Your algorithm computes the Levenshtein matrix. For computing the sequence of operations from the matrix look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849139/levenshtein-distance-inferring-the-edit-operations-from-the-matrix.

Comment: Hi i've spent the last few hours looking up the comments made and i'm no where.  I've searched google and the implementation of the algorithm appears differently each time i see it.  Nevyn, i understand what you're saying i think.  I set up 3 variables to increment but its dissecting the code so i know where each variable goes and thats where i'm still struggling.  Anyone else got any ideas it would be much appreciated!